# Можно ли в VS2017 Preview в Python по окончании программы консоль оставалась в режиме интерпретатора?

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-3.x, visual-studio-2017

Можно ли в VS2017 Preview в Python по окончании программы консоль оставалась в режиме интерпретатора?

а еще лучше, что бы программа запускалась в окошке с интерпретатором, который обычно закреплен внизу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нужно зайти в меню Отладка и там нажать "Выполнить файл в интерактивном окне Python" или нажать Shift+Alt+F5.
[image: скрин куда надо нажимать]
Еще вариант в свойствах проектах "Запуск > Аргументы интерпретатора" добавить параметр

> -i

Это приведет к переходу интерпретатора Python в интерактивный режим по завершении кода, после чего он ожидает нажатия клавиш CTRL+Z и ВВОД для выхода.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]