# В VS2017 Preview выполнить файл в интерактивном окне Python с текущей директории

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-3.x, visual-studio-2017

Нашел как [запускать в интерпретаторе код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661751/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-vs2017-preview-%D0%B2-python-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%80) и столкнулся с другой проблемой. Если запускать код в интерпретаторе, то текущая директория интерпретатора `C:\\Program Files\\Python36`. А хотелось что бы он автоматически переходил в директорию откуда запустился код. Такое возможно?

**Конкретная проблема:**
Если запускать через **консоль** программу которая выложена ниже, **то работает**, а если через интерпретатор, то нет.

```
name = 'file.txt'
with open(name) as fin1:
    for line in fin1:
        print(line)
```

Вариант решения это в коде программы поменять текущую директорию:

```
import os
import sys
print(sys.argv[0]) # имя запускаемого файла
path = sys.argv[0][:sys.argv[0].rindex('\\')] # выделяем только путь к файлу
os.chdir(path)
name = 'file.txt'
with open(name) as fin1:
    for line in fin1:
        print(line)
```

Так все корректно работает. Но это все равно не удобно, тк я не всегда запускаю свой код, а в чужом такие изменения не хорошо вставлять. Так можно ли  автоматически переходить в директорию откуда запустился код?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Текущая директория в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535318/23044)

Comment: в вашем конкретном случае, вы можете в настройках VS попробовать прописать рабочую директорию (установить равной `$(SolutionDir)`). В общем случае, см. по ссылке выше как получить файлы, путь к которым вы знаете только относительно вашего модуля (не имеет отношения к текущей рабочей директории) без `chdir()` (если я  вижу `open('file.txt')` в коде, я ожидаю, что file.txt находится в текущей рабочей директории, а не директории где сам скрипт живёт -- это могут быть разные папки).

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста куда именно я должен $(SolutionDir) прописать

Comment: менюшки конкретные я не знаю, посмотрите в свойствах проекта (правый клик на имени) -> Настройки.

Comment: здесь меняют дефолтную папку в консоли http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135480/change-default-visual-studio-command-prompt-location

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо в левом верхнем углу навестись на файл - и затем открыть папку, в которой вы работаете.